# IOS: restrict deletion of app or sending notification to parents(offline)

Tags: ios, iphone, parental-control

I am developing one parental control app in IOS.
This app will restrict kids to use iphone within set time periods.
and also I want to restrict kids with prompting "Enter password Dialog" while uninstalling this app.
(I know this isn't possbile).
So, I thought of sending SMS when user is about to uninstall the app. (not possible IOS will launch composer screen with message Text and kids need to approve that...also in airplane mode this won't work at all.)

is there any other alternative to restrict kids for deleting the app? 
or sending intimation to parent about this event???

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as it is handled by the system instead of your app. The only way to do this is with Restrictions (previously known as parental controls). Go to:

`Settings > General > Restrictions and turn off Deleting Apps.`

[image]

Comment: It's up to the parent/guardian to set a passcode when enabling this feature. Unless the child knows the 4-digit pin, it will be impossible for them to turn the feature off.

Comment: I think this passcode and phone lock password are same.

Comment: Only if you specifically set them to be the same. When you enable restrictions it prompts you to add a passcode. Why not just try it? It's easy to test the flow for yourself.